# How to get list of all products from OFBiz service?

Tags: java, service, product, ofbiz

I'm trying to get a list of all products which are available in the OFBiz system by calling a java service from my own event. I found a service which will return me one product depending on the productId which I passed to the service before. My problem is that I can't really find a service which returns me all products without passing a productId to it.

Here is a code example of my current service call:

```
    String param2 = "10000-001";
    Map input = UtilMisc.toMap("productId", param2);
    Map syncResults = null;
    try {
        syncResults = dispatcher.runSync("getProduct", input);
    } catch (GenericServiceException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    GenericValue test = (GenericValue) syncResults.get("product");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a service available that can serve your purpose, you just create one. In this case you can write something like:

```
    public static Map<String, Object> getAllProducts(DispatchContext dctx,
                Map<String, ? extends Object> context) {
         Map<String, Object> results = ServiceUtil.returnSuccess();
         Delegator delegator = dctx.getDelegator();
         //This will get all the products from the entity named Product
         List<GenericValue> productList = delegator.findByAnd("Product");
         //Do your stuff
         return results;  
}
```